# Rasbmc installed to usb does not boot if another usb-hdd is plugged in

Tags: boot, usb, raspbmc

I have Rasbmc installed to a USB data stick, and it boots fine. If however, I have another usb  hdd plugged in during boot, it throws the "kernel panic cannot mount root file system" error.
This same hdd works fine with the raspbmc if it is plugged in after the system boots.

This same setup with raspbmc installed to the sd card boots fine with all the above mentioned devices plugged in. Is there a way to stop Raspbmc from looking for the root file system on the Hdd?

**EDIT**
The following is my fstab:
proc            /proc           proc    defaults         0       0 
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=62$
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,noatime         0       0
UUID=dfddcb85-dcfb-424b-bced-8ae0b76f12f3  /               ext4    defaults,noa$
UUID="8CB4AF12B4AEFE38" /  ntfs-3g defaults 0 0

The first uuid (dfdd......) is the usb drive on which raspbmc is installed. The 2nd UUID (8CB.....) is the external HDD. The following settings have been tried for the external HDD:
UUID="8CB4AF12B4AEFE38" /  ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
UUID="8CB4AF12B4AEFE38" /dev/sdb  ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
UUID="8CB4AF12B4AEFE38" /media/8CB4AF12B4AEFE38  ntfs-3g defaults 0 0

Comment: Perhaps your USB HDD is drawing too much power when the kernel is trying to mount.  Have you tried booting with the HDD plugged into a powered USB hub?

Comment: Yes, the hdd is plugged in to a power hub

Answer (score 1):

Your RPi can't find correct 'boot device' when you plug your USB HDD. You can tell correct boot device name to Raspbmc installation via /etc/fstab file content like this. I'm using [BerryBoot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) with 4 linux distributions installed on USB stick ant is my /etc/fstab content:

proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
UUID=8208bc76-64af-4f8c-8fc0-96aa106f3dc2 / ext4 defaults,noatime   0   0
UUID="8E9420D19420BE19"     /media/MAXTOR   ntfs-3g defaults    0   0
UUID="D020C19620C183C6"     /media/SAMSUNG  ntfs-3g defaults    0   0

To find out UUID for devices use 'blkid' command.

Comment: i followed you instructions, and added the UUID to fstab, however it did not work. Still getting error "Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: UNable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)"
This is my fstab:

roc            /proc           proc    defaults         0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=62$
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,noatime         0       0
UUID=dfddcb85-dcfb-424b-bced-8ae0b76f12f3  /               ext4    defaults,noa$
UUID="8CB4AF12B4AEFE38" /  ntfs-3g defaults 0 0